# How to set log level for Jenkins in plugin tests

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm working on [workflow-durable-task-step Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-durable-task-step-plugin) and I want to debug one of the tests of this plugin. To understand the problem I need to see Jenkins logs. By default `INFO` level logs are shown during tests, but I need `FINE` level.

How to show all possible logs for internal Jenkins process during `mvn test` command?

I've tried to run tests like `mvn -Djava.util.logging.loglevel=FINEST test` but this option changes log level for test itself but not Jenkins internal process. I mean if I write something like `LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "Hello world");` in the body of my test - it will be show but no logs with `FINE` level of Jenkins process started by my test will be displayed.

Comment: If you find this answer addressed your problem, please mark as "Accepted" (the tick box). If you found it useful, please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `${JENKINS_URL}/log/levels`

Documentation: [Logger Configuration](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logger+Configuration)

Also see: [Viewing Logs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/)

Comment: Thx for the dwnvote, 2 years after the answer was provided! Haven't seen the OP back in 2 years either and OP could not bother to upvote/accept or comment. I'm reasonably sure it's because the entire answer is to guide the OP to the very thorough documentation which solves his problem. There is nothing clever or insightful to add. Reproducing the documentation to make my answer "stand on its own" is pointless as now I'd need to maintain my answer forever as the documentation/product changes. -2 in my motivation to contribute more.

Answer (score 0):

Within your test add something like the following:

```java
    @Rule
    public LoggerRule logs = new LoggerRule()
            .recordPackage(YourClass.class, Level.FINE)
```

The [LoggerRule](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-test-harness/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hudson/test/LoggerRule.java) ultimately is what you wanted